# shorter way to get an updated immutable object?

Tags: scala

I have a class with several parameters such as `class Building(val a: Int, val b: Int, val c: Int)`. This code I have to update it is this:

```
def updatedA(a: Int): Building = new Building(a, this.b, this.c)
def updatedB(b: Int): Building = new Building(this.a, b, this.c)
```

Is there a shorter way to get an updated object like the following?

```
def updatedA(newA: Int): Building = new { val a = newA } extends this // doesn't compile/ type is AnyRef instead of Building
```

Comment: How is that second idea going to be shorter or more straight-forward than your first idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at the `copyWith()` [construction mechanism](http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/32/) ?

> The copyWith method takes advantage of Scala 2.8's default arguments.
>   For each field in the class, it has a parameter which defaults to the
>   current value. Whichever arguments aren't specified will take on their
>   original values. We can call the method using named arguments (also in
>   Scala 2.8).
>
> val newJoe = joe.copyWith(phone = "555-1234")

Or check out the [copy mechanism](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/case-classes-in-28.html) for case classes.

> /*  The real power is the copy constructor that is automatically
>   generated in the case class.  I can make a copy with any or all
>   attributes modifed by using the copy constructor and declaring which
>   field to modify */
>
> scala> parent.copy(right = Some(node))

Comment: Awesome. Using shorthand notations like _ too much made me forget you can switch up the order of the arguments and pass them in with the (paramName = paramValue) notation.